# Sublime Text- how to add autocompletion of any Python module?

Tags: python, autocomplete, sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

This question is quite general, but I haven't found a straightforward answer yet.

Let's assume that I have installed a module to my site-packages folder in Python directory. Autocompletion in my Sublime Text with Sublime CodeIntel module don't really work. It works only with core python packages and even not all of them.

My current, default settings in codeintel config:

```
"codeintel_config": {
    "Python": {
        "env": {
            "PATH": "/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH",
            "PYTHONPATH": "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages:/usr/local/lib/python:$PYTHONPATH"
        }
```

These paths look quite strange, are they OK ? (I have default mac settings)

I am aware, that there are some other modules (for example Jedi, which requires some configuration), but I'm curious if there is a simple way of adding autocompletion of any Python module to ST ?

What if a module installs outside of site-packages - for example Kivy ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are the commented-out sample paths that the plugin comes with. You need to configure it with the an actual pythonpath for your system, which will vary depending on which python you are using (2 vs 3, system vs. python.org vs. homebrew, etc.)

If you want to get the actual path python is using, you could try:

```
python -c "import sys;print(':'.join(sys.path[1:]))"
```

(Or `python3` of course.) There might be more in there than you want to actually use though so pick out what you don't want..

Comment: Thanks. Maybe it's a stupid question, but what's the difference between PATH and PYTHONPATH here? I don't really understand how this works.

Comment: Maybe a stupid answer but `PATH` is where the system looks for programs you are invoking and I think that `PYTHONPATH` is for python exe and modules. It can be useful if you keep for example python2 and python3: according to the order you set in the path, you gave priority to one instead of the other.